# Integer to byte with given number of bits set

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know what to call this, which makes googling harder.

I have an integer, say `3`, and want to convert it to `11100000`, that is, a byte with the value of the integers number of bits set, from the most significantly bit.

I guess it could be done with:

```
byte result = 0;
for(int i = 8; i > 8 - 3; i--)
    result += 2 ^ i;
```

but is there anything faster / more nice or, preferably, standard library included in .net?

Comment: What if your integer is greater than 8?

Comment: Just a small point ^ is an Exclusive Or in C# not the Power operator.

Comment: @Martin Haha thanks, took me a few seconds just now to realize. Easy to forget sometimes, if you also happen to write equations for a paper while programming.

Comment: @Max, I only know this because I've made the same mistake 100s of times myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int n = 3; // 0..8 
int mask = 0xFF00;
byte result  = (byte) (mask >> n);
```

Comment: @Cameron, yes it is, since the result of `mask >> n` is of type `int`

Comment: @JimRhodes, I think the problem definition precludes that.

Answer (score 5):

Because there are only a few possibilities, you could just cache them:

```
// Each index adds another bit from the left, e.g. resultCache[3] == 11100000.
byte[] resultCache = { 0x00, 0x80, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0XF8, 0xFC, 0xFE, 0xFF };
```

You'd also get an exception instead of a silent error if you accidentally tried to get the value for n > 8.

Comment: +1 consolation prize for pointing out a simple & effective approach to many of these types of problems (table lookup) that is easily overlooked, and which all programmers should have in their box-of-tricks. (In this case it's not as good a solution as Henk's, though)

Comment: @JasonWilliams Thanks. I voted up Henk's elegant solution before posting this alternative :-).